# Getting empty data sets when creating test data [MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble trying to populate data so that I can perform some tests with it.

The following is my code:

```
for(i=0; i < 1000; i++){
    db.companies.insert({company: "Company"+i, employees: [""], CEO: ""})

    for(j=0; j < 50); j++){
        db.companies.update({"companies.company": "Company"+i}, {$push: {"companies.employees":
        "Employee"+Math.floor(Math.random()*500)}}, false, true)
    }

    db.companies.update({"companies.company": "Company"+i}, {$set: {"companies.CEO"
    : "CEO"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}})
}
```

The idea being that it creates 1,000 companies, and for each company it chooses 50 random employees from 500 that are available (I realize this method might result in duplicate employees, and that's fine). It then chooses one CEO for the company from 10 that are available.

The collection appears to be created correctly, and the company name will be generated correctly, but the employees list is empty and the CEO value is empty.

Is querying based on a dynamic name ({"companies.company": *"Company"+i*}) not allowed or am I just messing up somewhere?

Comment: Why are you searching for `companies.company` when the field name was just `company`? Same thing for a few other places. The collection name is `companies`, but you don't need to repeat that in the query/updates.

Comment: I thought I had seen some examples where that was done. Is companies.company equivalent to company?

Comment: See answer ... decided easier to explain there than in comments. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping the extra `companies` from your queries should work, as your documents are structured:

```
{ 
    Company: "Company1",
    Employees: [],
    CEO: ""
}
```

By using syntax that is:

```
db.companies.update({ "companies.company": "company1" }, ....)
```

You'd need a document like this:

```
{ 
    Companies: {     
        Company: "Company1",
        Employees: [],
        CEO: ""
    }
}
```

By using `db.companies.mongoDBFunction`, you've specified the collection as `companies` already.

Here's code that should work:

```
for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++){
    var name = "Company" + i;
    db.companies.insert({company: name, employees: [""], CEO: ""});

    for(var j=0; j < 50; j++){
        db.companies.update({"company": name }, {$push: {"employees":
        "Employee"+Math.floor(Math.random()*500)}}, false, true)
    }

    db.companies.update({"company": name}, {$set: {"CEO"
    : "CEO"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}})
}
```